# CakePHP findListBy – findAllBy equivalent

Tags: cakephp

**I'd like to know, how I could extend CakePHP by a *Magic Find Function* called findListBy(...) doing the same as findAllBy(...) but returning a list**

I'm looking for a findAllBy equivalent doing the same but returning a find('list', ...) instead of find('all', ...).

If there is not any function like this, how could I implement such a function by myself? I don't really know, how the *Magic Find Types* work :(

Thanks in advance

**EDIT** Please compare the length of the commands. Both commands should return the same array:

```
// The common find('list', ...)
$post = $this->User->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array('user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
    'fields' => array('Post.user_id', 'Post.id')
));

// findListByUserId(...)
$post = $this->User->findListByUserId($this->Auth->user('id'), array('Post.user_id, 'Post.id'));
```

**And YES**: The structure of the array returned is desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Mapped methods

The magic `findAllBy` method is implemented [directly in the query method](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php#L525) - it's not possible to add new permutations to that without overwriting the dbo class in use.

However, method names do not need to map one to one to a real method - the way to define your own dynamic model functions is to create a behavior and define [mappedMethods](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html#mapped-methods). Adapted to the question that would be:

```
class MyBehavior extends ModelBehavior {

    public $mapMethods = array('/^findListBy/' => 'doSomething');

    public function doSomething(Model $model, $method, $arg1, $arg2) {
        // copy method name logic from DboSource::query
        
        return $Model->find('list', $params);
    }
}
```

Though, it has to be said that using dynamic method names is much less flexible than building a params array and just calling `find('list', $params)`.

Comment: How can I get the name of the function being called? I would like to know which fields follow _findListBy_

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. The only arguments I got are the model, the array of fields and the array of the desired order.

Comment: Lol what do you expect me to debug when _debug(func_get_args());_ only displays the model object, the array of fields and the array of the desired order

Comment: debugging does not mean "use the debug function" it means: investigate. [This is the method in the current version](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/BehaviorCollection.php#L215) that dispatches a behavior call - debug it. Also "it doesn't work" doen't tell me anything at all about what you've done, and you don't mention what version of CakePHP you are using, so I can't link you to the exact method for your install. (Why did you accept an answer before checking if it solved your problem?). Good luck :).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is, it's call `find()`:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find

I actually never saw the need to use those magic wrappers. Neither for all nor list nor count.

Especially as they provide 0 possibility for type hinting and method param hinting or doc block information while using them.

Tip:

Use the model layer to write your complex querys and then access those wrappers from outside.
This way the access is still short while the whole query building stays in the model.
You also keep your typehinting etc.

EDIT: part of the answer was in the comment. revised to make it clearer what the full answer is here.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, but when using find('list', ...) I need to specify the _conditions_ array and the _fields_ array for my use and this would end in a 4-line command instead of a 1-line command I'd have, if there was any command like findListBy<FieldName>(...).

Comment: You can leverage your model to wrap those. Then you will have single line commands again for your controller and other places where you need it.

Comment: Yea, that's my plan, but I'd like to keep the _Magic_. Maybe I'd like to use `$this->Model->findListByIdAndOtherId(...)` in the future.

Comment: -1 as it doesn't answer the question, only states an opinion. @lenny.myr it's only 1 line - because you chose to write it like that - in comparison to the `find('list'` example it is **3** lines long if written in a similar format, i.e. it is only one line shorter (and arguably less readable - note that it's necessary to scroll to read the end of the line here on stack overflow).

Comment: Sry, but using find() wrapped in the model layer is a possible way of maintaining both short access and type hinting. Therefore it can't be marked as just an opinion. It also has some ground of an answer. A valid one IMO.